# How set system time android programmatically?

Tags: java, android, time

i need change my system date ( time ) after launch application , it is possible in android programmatically  ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need `android.permission.SET_TIME`.
Use the `AlarmManager` via `Context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)` method `setTime()`.

Snippet:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2014, 9, 29, 18, 19, 00);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setTime(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```